# How to get database values after click Next button and without reload the jsp page?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets, ejb-3.0

I have Next and Previous button in my jsp page.I want to load the data set when user click the Next button without reload the page. Also all the data should not come at once from the oracle database.If only user click the next button, then it should have to retrieve the next value set and display.( to avoid server failure ) So how can I write my oracle sql query to get data after clicking Next button and how can I implement my jquery function to load the data without reload the page?. In here  my data table dosen't include headers also all the data should not be carried from database at once. So it's hard to use jquery predefined libraries. My main problem is how to write sql to carry data when click Next button.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4112686/1065197 (I can't vote the question as dup)

Comment: I don't understand why people upvote duplicated questions and doesn't provide even a comment about it.

Comment: You should show what you have already tried so far. The general idea is, have your queries support pagination via `limit` and `offset` keywords, call yor backend-side methods that execute those queries via ajax, digest the response and update the DOM via JS.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza maybe because it's not a duplicate?

Comment: @namero999 it is a duplicate since OP needs to execute an Ajax call to a Servlet and that Q/A covers this topic in details. The fact that you're going to use a business class or an EJB in your servlet `doGet` or `doPost` implementation is a design matter. Even if its not a duplicate, the question is too broad to be answered here (otherwise provide an answer).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It's not that every question that has Ajax as part of the solution is a duplicate of that famous answer. If you read the question carefully, the OP also need to know concepts like pagination, something that is not covered in the answer you linked. I do not provide an answer because the question is too broad, still I want the OP to read the comments and get a clue, before the question gets smashed.

Comment: @namero999 then the question should be splitted in two questions. And both would be duplicated questions :).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza it's not a duplicate, it's a valid question with a clear answer. The fact that the answer is so obvious to many of us, doesn't mean it was obvious to the OP.

Comment: @PA. looks like not only me thinks of this question as a duplicated.

Comment: I want to carry data from database only if user click the Next button.All the data should not carry at once.Usually jquery tables are used when all the data come at once.But my situation is not like that.